# Circle not happening anywhere other than 0,0?

Tags: c, opengl, geometry

so this works fine if I make the origin (0,0) but here I am trying to make it work at (20,20) and the shape isn't a circle at all. What is going on here?

```
const unsigned int triangles = 20; // number of triangles
        const float twoPi = 2.0f * 3.14159f;
        const double radius = 0.1;
        int i;
        float delta = twoPi / triangles;
        glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_FAN);
        glVertex2f(20/window_w,20/window_h); // origin

        for(i = 0; i <= triangles; i++)
          glVertex2f((20/window_w)+(radius * cos(i *  delta)),
             (20/window_h)+(radius * sin(i * delta)));
        glEnd();
```

Comment: Don't even bother with changing your vertex values to move the circle to different locations. You should be tackling this problem using matrix transformation. In particular `glTranslatef (...)` would help tremendously. Remember to set the matrix mode to `GL_MODELVIEW` and load the identity before trying this though. You'll probably want to push/pop the ModelView matrix too. Whatever place you learned about immediate mode from should cover everything I just mentioned.

Comment: Suspect your shift to center (20,20) should use something like ` glVertex2f(20 + window_w/2, 20 + window_h/2)`.